# tab bar image displayed good in storyboard but not in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem. I add some png files to my project, in my root folder. I have a tabbar controller. On each view, I changed the title and the picture of each items.

In my storyboard, images and title are well displayed. But when I launched the app on the simulator, titles and images are not set...

I tried to clean / build the solution, disconnect the simulator, reconnect it, exit XCode, launch it again.

Have you an idea why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution !

If it could be useful for someone...

In the "copy bundle Ressources", the Main.storyboard wasn't here. I just added it, rebuild, run again, and all works !

Answer (score 1):

I actually did not add images under Assests.xcassets. After I relocated images from other location in the project to Assests.xcassets, images are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in my app, i replaced default tabbar buttons with custom buttons and gave background image to that with more easy customisation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you a tutoriel for do that ?

Comment: I dont have any tutorial, but this is very simple, just remove your tabbar buttons and replace with your custom UIButtons with custom images :)